# Starting a GameWindow in a thread

Tags: c#, .net, opentk

I'm trying to write an OpenTK application where you can type commands in a console window, and have a GameWindow display the result of commands.

My code looks like this:

```
public Program : GameWindow
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var display = new Program();
        var task = new Task(() => display.Run());
        task.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            //communicate with the display object asynchronously
         }
    }
}
```

However, the display window does not appear when started in a task or thread.

Why is this the case? I need the Run method to happen in a thread, because it is blocking for the life of the window.

Comment: I think your best bet is to do your windowing on the main thread and the other task in a separate thread. Or, you could do all the work in the Load method of the window...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your particular problem, just create instance of your window ("display" in your case) on thread itself:

```
public class Program : GameWindow {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Program display = null;
        var task = new Thread(() => {
            display = new Program();
            display.Run();
        });
        task.Start();
        while (display == null)
            Thread.Yield(); // wait a bit for another thread to init variable if necessary

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            //communicate with the display object asynchronously
            display.Title = response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why GameWindow doesn't work in a closure? Seems bizarre

Comment: Why it doesn't work? It does using code above. If you mean why you have create window on the same thread where you run it - probably the same thread affinity as in many GUI applications (like windows forms and wpf).

Comment: Trying to close the window and open a new one in another new thread opens a set of issues (cleanup on unload, GLFWException on another window creation). I wonder whether there is a way to properly expand this example into complete window life cycle.